# Nuxt server middleware with generate

Tags: express, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I think i'm misunderstanding nuxt server middleware. I have an api directory with a single file that spins up express and writes records to a mysql database. Everything works as expected running in dev, but after nuxt generate, that endpoint always returns a 404.

Can you use nuxt generate with an internal API that runs on the server? I'd be using axios to hit this endpoint for what it's worth but I doubt that makes a difference.

from Nuxt config:

```
{
  target: static, 
  serverMiddleware: [{ path: '/api', handler: '~/api/index.js' }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Server middleware basically allows you to run your own code on the server nuxt spins up for you in `target: 'server'` mode. Therefore your approach won't work in static mode, as there is no server running your middleware. You are only serving static files. In dev mode you are running a server locally, which is why your middleware works fine there.

For it to work in production you have two options:

- Run nuxt in `target: 'server'` mode, instead of generating static files
- Spin up your express server separately, instead of using server middleware in nuxt

I hope you understand how server middleware works now and you can make the right decision for your project!

Comment: Thanks Florian, got that part. But, now how do I run the site without a dist directory? It says listening on localhost but I want it to run from a local vhost like mynuxtsite.com?

Comment: @MattKaye I suppose you mean running in `target: 'server';` mode by saying 'without a dist directory'. I'm not experienced with setting up a vhost, but you can take a look at the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-server).